# Simular o tipo booleano em C

Tags: c, tipagem, booleano

Qual a maneira mais apropriada para simular o tipo `bool` em C? Meu professor fez isso de maneira bem simplória.

```
#define bool int
```

Mas também encontrei uma resposta excelente [aqui](https://allanlima.wordpress.com/2006/11/07/simulando-o-tipo-boolean-em-c/) (segue uma cópia do código).

```
// Criando a enumeração:
enum boolean {
    true = 1, false = 0
};
// Permitindo a sua declaração como um tipo qualquer:
typedef  enum boolean  bool;

// Agora podemos escrever e compilar os códigos como:
int main () {

    bool b = true;
    if (b) {
        b = false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Quais os prós e contras de ambos os tipos de declaração e onde eles podem me causar dor de cabeça no futuro caso eu os implemente em uma biblioteca?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A melhor opção é esta:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Isto requer um compilador compatível com C99, que virtualmente são todos que contam, você poderá usar o tipo `_Bool`. Se não tiver um compilador assim, o mesmo que o padrão faz:

```
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1
 
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ > 201710L
/* FIXME: We should be issuing a deprecation warning here, but cannot yet due
 * to system headers which include this header file unconditionally.
 */
#elif !defined(__cplusplus)
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
/* Define _Bool as a GNU extension. */
#define _Bool bool
#if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus < 201103L
/* For C++98, define bool, false, true as a GNU extension. */
#define bool bool
#define false false
#define true true
#endif
```

[Fonte](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).