# Como inativar um elemento em C?

Tags: c, modelagem

A partir das seguintes `structs`, gostaria de saber como inativar um imóvel.

> Uma imobiliária dispõe de um conjunto de 100 imóveis para aluguel. Sobre cada imóvel a aplicação deve permitir armazenar: o tipo de imóvel, localização, morada, preço mínimo, preço aconselhado, ano de construção, permite animais, obs ... A aplicação deve permitir : "Inativar um imóvel...

```
typedef struct imoveis{
    int tipo, cod;
    int ano;
    char cidade[100], morada[100], animais[20], obs[100]; 
    float preco_min, preco_acons;
}INFO;

typedef struct imovel{
    INFO info;
    struct imovel *seguinte;
    struct imovel *anterior; 
}IMOVEL;
```

Comment: Defina "inativar um imóvel", por favor.

Comment: A questão em causa é: Inativar um imóvel: A possibilidade de aluguer do imóvel pode ser inativada por
um período de tempo, por exemplo para obras;

Comment: De onde tirou esse trecho de texto? É um enunciado ou algo assim? Se for, seria interessante postá-lo por completo na pergunta.

Comment: Pode adicionar uma Flag, com o nome de Ativo e colocar o valor 1 para simbolizar imóvel ativo e 0 para inativo.

Comment: "Uma imobiliária dispõe de um conjunto de 100 imóveis para aluguer. Sobre cada imóvel a
aplicação deve permitir armazenar: o tipo de imóvel, localização,
morada, preço mínimo, preço aconselhado, ano de construção, permite animais, obs ... A aplicação deve permitir : "Inativar um imóvel..."

Comment: @AnaP A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Algumas considerações sobre este código:

Estranho uma estrutura que guarda dados de UM imóvel chamar `imoveis`. E uma lista de imóveis chamar `imovel`. Piora quando o tipo dessa estrutura passa se chamar `INFO`.

`float` não é adequado para valores monetários. Mas tudo bem para um exercício, desde que entenda que não deveria usar em produção, até porque em produção é improvável que se usar *array* de char para representar *strings*. Provavelmente até usaria em `ano`, se ele for só descritivo, como parece ser o caso. Só faria sentido ser `int` se vai fazer contas com ele. Não posso falar se outros tipos são adequados por não conhecer os requisitos.

Quanto ao status de atividade pode usar um simples `char` para guardar esta informação. Ali poderia guardar S ou N, ou 0 ou 1 como caractere ou como código ASCII. Poderia usar um `int` também, mas não parece ser a melhor opção. Dependendo do compilador poderia [usar um `bool`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198958/101), ou pode simulá-lo: [Simular o tipo booleano em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95812/101).

```
typedef struct {
    int tipo, cod;
    int ano;
    char cidade[100], morada[100], animais[20], obs[100]; 
    float preco_min, preco_acons;
    char ativo;
} Imovel;

typedef struct {
    Imovel info;
    struct imovel *seguinte;
    struct imovel *anterior; 
} Imoveis;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Property.c).

Quando for inicializar precisa adotar um padrão semântico para este campo. Algo assim:

```
imovel.ativo = 1;
```

ou

```
imovel.ativo = '1';
```

ou

```
imovel.ativo = 'S';
```

Isto vale mais ou menos para qualquer campo que tenha um conjunto limitado e previamente conhecido de opções. Se for 2, 3, em tese até 256 (pode usar um `enum` se o compilador permitir, em alguns casos são 2 mas não é algo booleano, não é questão de ser só um sim ou não, no caso de um *status*, mesmo que comece com 2 pode ser que tenha algo intermediário mais pra frente, então pode ser útil. Se precisa passar de 256 opções ainda pode usar um `short` ou `int`, embora quando tem muita opção nem sempre é interessante ter uma simulação de enumeração como esta.

Comment: Sobre definir um `enum` para os valores de `ativo`, qual sua opinião?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss como eu edite? Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50363/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180014/101